# C# winforms password manager with two way hashing

Tags: c#, encryption

I am creating a password manager and using sha512 hashing and salt to store the password in a sql database.

All well and good so far, but I need my app to work like keepass for example as I want to be able to store long and complex passwords that cannot possibly be remembered.

Obviously one way hashing is useless in this case!

Comment: Use something like AES to encrypt the passwords. Hashes are one-way, and in this use case that isn't what you want. You'll want to use a key derivation algorithm (e.g. PBKDF2) to take the user password and generate an AES key with it. LastPass documents how they keep passwords safe (high level) [here](https://www.lastpass.com/security/what-if-lastpass-gets-hacked).

Comment: *two way hashing* ?  I guess, you encryption/decryption.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming or C# ... yet.

Comment: Yes it is about C# as that is the language I am using.